# JSON to Pandas dataframe. How to parse inner parts of JSON

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to parse a json and insert the results in pandas dataframe.

My json looks like

```
{'result': {'data': [{'dimensions': [{'id': '219876173',
      'name': 'Our great product'},
     {'id': '2021-03-01', 'name': ''}],
    'metrics': [41, 4945]},
   {'dimensions': [{'id': '219876173',
      'name': 'Our great product'},
     {'id': '2021-03-02', 'name': ''}],
    'metrics': [31, 2645]},
   {'dimensions': [{'id': '219876166',
      'name': 'Our awesome product'},
     {'id': '2021-03-01', 'name': ''}], ....
```

So far, I've managed to get to this point:

```
[{'dimensions': [{'id': '219876173',
    'name': 'Our great product'},
   {'id': '2021-03-01', 'name': ''}],
  'metrics': [41, 4945]},
 {'dimensions': [{'id': '219876173',
    'name': 'Our great product'},
   {'id': '2021-03-02', 'name': ''}],
  'metrics': [31, 2645]},
```

However, when I place it in Pandas I get

```
   dimensions                                                                metrics
0   [{'id': '219876173', 'name': 'Our great product...   [41, 4945]
1   [{'id': '219876173', 'name': 'Our great product...   [31, 2645]
2   [{'id': '219876166', 'name': 'Our awesome product...   [27, 2475]
```

I can now manually split the results in columns using some lambdas

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(r.json().get('result').get('data'))
df['delivered_units'] = df['metrics'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['revenue'] = df['metrics'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
df['name'] = df['dimensions'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['sku'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: x['name'])
```

Is there a better way to parse json directly without lambdas?

Comment: Kindly post your expected output. Data not pics please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into flatten_json:

```
data = {'result': {'data': [{'dimensions': [{'id': '219876173',
      'name': 'Our great product'},
     {'id': '2021-03-01', 'name': ''}],
    'metrics': [41, 4945]},
   {'dimensions': [{'id': '219876173',
      'name': 'Our great product'},
     {'id': '2021-03-02', 'name': ''}],
    'metrics': [31, 2645]},
   {'dimensions': [{'id': '219876166',
      'name': 'Our awesome product'},
     {'id': '2021-03-01', 'name': ''}]}]}}

from flatten_json import flatten
dic_flattened = (flatten(d, '.') for d in data['result']['data'])
df = pd.DataFrame(dic_flattened)

  dimensions.0.id    dimensions.0.name dimensions.1.id dimensions.1.name  metrics.0  metrics.1
0       219876173    Our great product      2021-03-01                         41.0     4945.0
1       219876173    Our great product      2021-03-02                         31.0     2645.0
2       219876166  Our awesome product      2021-03-01                          NaN        NaN
```